# Setting up an ini file in grails

Tags: grails, ini, shiro

I am trying to use an ini file to login into a grails application with the shiro plugin. I have created an ini file and put it in the config folder. The ini is displayed below.

```
[main]

[users]
admin=heslo, Administrator

[roles]
Administrator = *

[urls]
```

I created a service with the method `createSecurityManager()` which I call at bootstrap:

```
def createSecurityManager() {
    Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
    SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
    println securityManager
    SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    securityManager
}
```

When I try logging in using the username `admin` and password `heslo`, the login fails.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the quick-start described in the plugin documentaion?
http://grails.org/plugin/shiro

In order to use an ini-file, I guess you have to create your own realm.

When using the grails shiro plugin, I think the easiest way to use it is to create the standard DB-Realm and initialize it in the bootstrap - the same way the quick-start describes it :-)

Answer (score 0):

But the Shiro CAS configuration should be done using the ini file approach right?
I've been referring to this link: http://shiro.apache.org/cas.html
Is there a way to configure CAS authentication with the quick-start approach that comes without an ini config?